# Extract Value to Points using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, ndvi, extract, value-extraction

I am using ArcMap.

I am trying to extract NDVI values to my point data. However, when I use the tool Extract Values to Points the error is generated as:-

[image]

I think they have same Projected Coordinate system as shown below (1) Point Data & (2) NDVI raster data :-
[image]

[image]

Why is this issue occurring and how do I solve it?

Comment: It looks like you are using Event XY Layer. Try to export the Event layer to a Point layer either in shapefile or gdb and try again.

Comment: Would you like to use python for gis? I think is easier

Comment: Please always provide errors as formatted text rather than in a picture.